# MMO Connection Trouble

Tags: java, netty, mmo

my question is the following i have this design for my mmorpg

Client -> Authentication Server -> Game World -> Client -> Authentication server.... And so on

The client uses IO for the connection, the authentication server uses netty, so here comes the question each world connection ( a simple socket ) is stored in the authentication server for transfering data to the corresponding world so for example player a sends a movement request from the client, this Will be directed to the authentication server and then the authentication server grab the user world id, then the authentication server contacts the world, now how would the world write a response back to the user ( the client ) using the same socket?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miss understand what you did but normally it should be as easy as just use the Channel.writeAndFlush(...) method.